# Scala VSCode, metals intellisense not working correctly

Tags: scala, visual-studio-code, mill, scala-metals

This code does compile and run with mill, but intellisense shows error "object pwd is not a member of package foo.os bloop"

```
//main.scala
package foo

object Exercise{
    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
        println(os.pwd)
    }
}
```

```
//build.sc
import mill._, scalalib._

object foo extends ScalaModule {
  def scalaVersion = "2.13.1"

  def ivyDeps = Agg(
    ivy"com.lihaoyi::os-lib:0.7.8"
  )
}
```

I have metals vscode extension and it does recognize os-lib in project libraries. And it does show type for the os.pwd, but it still shows the error.

Comment: Did you imported the **mill** build definition and the reloaded the build server?

Comment: Through the metals extension I imported build and restarted build server, didn't help.

Comment: May I recommend asking in the [**metals** **discord** server](https://discord.gg/3eHeFJ2XhJ).

Comment: what does the "metals: run doctor" action says?
edit: if it doesn't show any problem, have you saved your file? Metals only recompiles the files on save

Answer (score 5):

On occasions VS Code's Scala plugin Metals suddenly stops working, and I get red lines under everything, and intellisense stop working, even when `sbt compile` works fine.

I found a simple fix that got Metals under VS Code back to working again:

```bash
# Exit VS Code
cd your/project/dir
rm -rf .bloop
rm -rf .metals

# Sometimes a running bloop can cause problems so find and stop it
ps -ef | grep -i bloop

kill <bloop process id>

code .
```

It seems like Bloop and Metals got into an inconsistent state, and deleting the hidden directories will force both to restart.